# Git won't add file I am changing and there is no gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have this file inside my project, and no matter how many changes I make to it, git won't add the change.

There is no .gitignore file. And the file is inside the project. I did try --force and I tried git add --all. Nothing helps. I do remember using git add on the entire directory where the file is. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: What's the output of `git status`?

Comment: `git add *` and then commit the file?

Comment: The message I am getting after a commit is: nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: It is just one file in that directory. And it is not inside .gitignore.

Answer (score -1):

I never saw a single .gitignore file that prevented me from adding and committing the file in question. However I do remember removing that file from commit using Tortoise.

In any case, I solved the issue by renaming the file, adding it, and committing it, and later on, giving the file its former name.